# Reachability vs UIDevice-Reachability

Tags: iphone, reachability

I need to test network reachability in my iPhone project. Which project is better to use?

[Reachability](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html) vs 
[UIDevice-Reachability](https://github.com/erica/uidevice-extension/blob/master/UIDevice-Reachability.h)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reachability if your only issue is to test network reachability. It's apple sample code and it's pretty easy to use.

UIDevice is great for learning but a bit overkill just for network reachability. So in the end either of them will do. Depends on what you want to do.

Comment: Thanks that is what i wanted to hear!