# how to display alert when networking connection is disable?

Tags: iphone

i am new to iphone in my app i am connecting to database through web services it working correctly,but i want to displat alert  when network connection is disable.please any help me how to alert when net connection is disable,
  thanks in advance.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4954904/reachability-vs-uidevice-reachability and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1861656/iphone-reachability-checking

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this [S.O. entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6019596/best-practice-nsurlconnection/6020088#6020088)

In particular, the main point of interest for you is the first one, about using the Reachability framework to detect network connectivity.

Answer (score 0):

Use [UIAlertView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html)  to display alerts

Answer (score 0):

When you get notified by your delegate/Observer for the network disable state, you could show message in `UIAlertView`.

```
 //show an alert to let the user know that they can't connect...
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Network Status" message:@"Network is not available. Please try again later." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
```

you could also use the [Reachability](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html) API's to know the state of network connection.

[iPhone SDK: Testing Network Reachability](http://www.raddonline.com/blogs/geek-journal/iphone-sdk-testing-network-reachability/)